# save the contents of a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

im writing a code to save the contents of a form and when asked to display it should open as a form itself. like how i have saved it

ive tried this

```
Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
' Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the file assigned to the Save button.
Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Excel Files|*.xls|Word Files|*.doc"
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "R:\Clinical\General\Shifts"
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Shift File"
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

but wen i open the from ,it displays in notepad since its a .txt file. but i want it to open as a form itself.
help me pls.

Comment: Can you save the content in a database, then reload from the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to save an image of the form:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.bmp"
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))
    bmp.Save(strFilename)
    bmp.Dispose()
  End Sub
```